# String, Substring, and if-else Statements in Change- Making Program

Tags: java, string, if-statement, substring

I just started a Java class this week, and we have our first project due on Sunday that I'm having a bit of trouble on. The basic jist of the project is that we have to create a program that calculates the change given back after a purchase, and tell the user how many quarters, dimes, and nickels make up said change.

The problem is that the teacher wants the input to be in the form 'pay:cost', which doesn't lend itself well to any of the primitive types. So he suggested using a string and substring to separate the 'pay' and 'cost' from the colon, but I'm not sure how to do that. 'Pay' and 'cost' also have to be numbers in a specific range, which I figure is what if-else statements are for. The problem is that I don't have a firm grasp on the syntax and need some help setting it up.

Here are the instructions he gave for the project verbatim, as well as the code that I have right now. Keep in mind that this is baby's first project, so please be merciful. Any help is appreciated.

Instructions:

1.) You must check that the data entered by the user follows the required syntax. If not, your program must display an error dialog and exit. The input is valid only if all of the following hold: 

- The input has the form pay:cost where pay and cost are both integers. 
- pay is a whole number of dollars (100, 200, 300, ...). 
- pay is less than or equal to 900 cents. 
- pay is greater than or equal to cost. 
- cost is greater than or equal to 5 and can be expressed using only quarters, dimes and nickels (i.e. 5, 10, 15, ... 95, 100, 105, ... 890, 895, or 900).

2.) If the input is valid, then your program must display a message dialog showing the minimum number of nickels, dimes and quarters needed to provide the correct amount of change, where change = pay - cost.

3.) Your program must exit when the user closes the output message dialog.

4.) You can ONLY import javax.swing.JOptionPane

Code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ChangeMakerWindow {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String amountString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount you pay in cents,\n" +
            "followed by the cost of the item in cents.\n" +
            "The input must be in the form: pay:cost,\n" +
            "where pay is a whole number (100, 200, 300, etc) to a maximum of 900,\n" +
            "and cost is  a multiple of five (5, 10, 15, etc) to a maximum of 900");

    int pay, cost, change, originalChange, quarters, dimes, nickles;
    change = pay - cost;
    originalChange = change;

    quarters = change / 25;
    change = change % 25;
    dimes = change / 10;
    change = change %10;
    nickles = change / 5;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, originalChange +
            " cents in coins can be given as:\n" +
            quarters + " quarters\n" +
            dimes + " dimes\n" +
            nickles + " nickles\n");
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: I implemented a basic solution to help you get pay and cost. The rest is really basic logic on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use String.split(":") to make pay and cost two separate items. Then convert to integers with Integer.parseInt(String s).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String amountString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount you pay in cents,\n" +
        "followed by the cost of the item in cents.\n" +
        "The input must be in the form: pay:cost,\n" +
        "where pay is a whole number (100, 200, 300, etc) to a maximum of 900,\n" +
        "and cost is  a multiple of five (5, 10, 15, etc) to a maximum of 900");

  int pay, cost, change, originalChange, quarters, dimes, nickles;

  //this is the real meat of the solution
  String[] input = amountString.split(":");  //this creates a String array with 2 parts {"pay", "cost"}
  pay = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);  //This method (and the next) parse as int.
  cost = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
  change = pay - cost;
  originalChange = change;

  quarters = change / 25;
  change = change % 25;
  dimes = change / 10;
  change = change %10;
  nickles = change / 5;

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, originalChange +
        " cents in coins can be given as:\n" +
        quarters + " quarters\n" +
        dimes + " dimes\n" +
        nickles + " nickles\n");
  System.exit(0);   //Note, unlike C++ This is unnecessary.
 //When the method ends there is no need to call System.exit(0);
 //The only time to use System.exit(0) is when it's outside of control flow.
 //The system was already going to end from the main method anyway so it doesn't change anything.
 //Pro tip: using return; (with nothing there) will also do the same thing.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first step of splitting pay:cost would be to use a string.split() method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

The proper syntax for your if-else statements would be

```
if (pay > minimum_range || pay < maximum_range){
    do things

else{
    do other things 
}
```

The above statement reads "if pay is greater than minimum range OR less than maximum range then do things.

To check if they have the following syntax you would want to do the following.

Check that the only 'chars' you have in the input string are 0-9 and the colon. You can do this using regular expressions but you're probably too new for that so I would recommend using a simple for loop to iterate through the string.

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    if str.charAt(i) != Digit or Colon
        print error message
}
```

Afterwards you can do pay - cost and find the appropriate 'change'. Then you can loop through starting from the largest amount (a quarter) and keep subtracting X number of quarters till you can't anymore. And then subtract dimes, then nickles, then pennies until you're done.

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried using that code to check for characters other than 0-9 and the colon. But Java isn't recognizing 'Digit' or 'Colon' as acceptable values. Also for the 'i", should I be replacing that with either 'pay' or 'cost'?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate `pay:cost` to `pay` and `cost` with `substring` you will have to know first where the `:` is. So, to get the position in which the `:` it's located you can use `indexOf()` function in your `String`, in my example, `myString`.

```
String myString = "pay:cost";

int position = myString.indexOf("%");
```

And now you can `substring` the `String` that you have. I'm going to create two variables to store the two parts that are generated.

```
String pay = "";
String cost = "";

pay = myString.substring(0,position - 1);
cost = myString.substring(position + 1, myString.length());
```

**Note:** If you want to make the same but more clearly you can use `split` function. It makes an array of `Strings` that takes as reference the `:`, as follows:

```
String[] strings = myString.split(":");
pay = strings[0]; --> "pay"
cost = strings[1]; --> "cost"
```

After, if you want to convert those `Strings` to `ints` you just have to do:

```
int payInt = Integer.parseInt(pay);
int costInt = Integer.parseInt(cost);
```

If you have some doubts about the code that I put above please let me know.

I expect it will be helpful for you!